# Show ProgressBar when changing fragment - Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a fragment inside my app that does a lot of background work, and therefore takes a long time to load. I want to show a ProgressBar from my Main Activity and hide it once the fragment is loaded.

The problem is, that wither the progressbar doesn't show, or it gets stuck, since the whole UI freezes.

How can I show the ProgressBar while the fragment is loading?
Thanks.

Edit: Code inside fragment:

```
  public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your fragment here

        fragments = new Fragment[]
       {
           new HalachotFragment(),
           new BooksFragment(),
       };

        var titles = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(new[]
       {
                "הלכות",
                "ספרים",
        });

        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager, fragments, titles);

    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HalachaSection, container, false);

        //var progressBar = Activity.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);

        halachotPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.halachotPager);

        halachotPager.Adapter = tabsAdapter;
        halachotPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;
        halachotPager.SetCurrentItem(1, true);
        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        tabs = Activity.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);

        tabs.SetupWithViewPager(halachotPager);
        //var toolbar = Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        tabs.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        //progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        return view;

    }
```

BookFragment:

```
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Books, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.booksRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.NestedScrollingEnabled = false;

        mBooks = new List<Book>();
        ImageView cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        //cover = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.coverImage);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Torat_Hamachane1);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "תורת המחנה א' - הלכות יום ויום", Cover = cover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.Torat_Hamachane1}); 

        //Create our layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Activity, 2);
        mLayoutManager.AutoMeasureEnabled = true;
        //mRecyclerView.SetForegroundGravity(GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        SimpleItemAnimator x = null;

        mRecyclerView.SetItemAnimator(x);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mBooks, mRecyclerView, Activity);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.kitzurTHM);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "קיצור תורת המחנה - הלכות יום ויום ושבת", Cover = cover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.kitzurTHM, Content = "KitzurTHM/KitzurTHMFull.html" });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        ImageView newCover = new ImageView(Activity);
        newCover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.halkasPurim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "הלכה כסדרה - הלכות פורים", Cover = newCover, imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.halkasPurim });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.halkasPesach);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "הלכה כסדרה - הלכות פסח", Cover = cover, imageResourceId= Resource.Drawable.halkasPesach });

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.netzach);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "שו\"ת נצח יהודה", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.netzach});

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.tankim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "טיפול בטנקים בשבת", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.tankim});

        cover = new ImageView(Activity);
        cover.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.tipulBeChalalim);
        mBooks.Add(new Book() { Title = "טיפול בחללים בשבת", Cover = cover , imageResourceId = Resource.Drawable.tipulBeChalalim, Content = "TipulBechalalimShabbat.html" });

        Refresh();
        return view;

    }
```

HalachotFragment parses a document, which also makes it take a long time.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: are you using asynctask for background work?

Comment: since the whole UI freezes. means not doing work in work Thread? show some part of code

Comment: Which code? Inside the fragment? or the transaction??

Comment: @amitairos: code due to Fragment taking time in loading

Comment: Update: Added code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProgressBar in your main activity and Make Progressbar object static now whenever you change the fragment show that progressbar and when your fragment loaded hide that progressbar.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try `runOnUiThread` as the following code whenever Fragment is Change,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Testing...");
        pd.show();

    }
});
```

If you want hide the `ProgressDialog` means use,

```
pd.hide();
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please look at my code and tell me how to use Async to make it not freeze the UI? Also, where should I put this code? After the fragment transaction?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to post some portion of code.

> How can I show the ProgressBar while the fragment is loading?

When you'r calling fragment from activity then `onAttach()` method for fragment will be called. So at that time you need to take your activity object reference in  that method. Like ,

```
MainActivity mainActivity; // this should be global
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
}
```

So using activity object you can access your progress bar object and hide it in `setUserVisibleHint()` method in which fragment will be loaded completely.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      // hide progress bar
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please look at my code and tell me how to use Async to make it not freeze the UI?